# Как это исправить чтобы каждый словарь в JSON выводился с новой строки, а то в редакторе подсвечивает ошибку

Tags: json

Как исправить?

```
{
    "none": []
}{
    "none": []
}
```

Comment: в редакторе ошибка потому что запятой нет

Comment: я записываю данные из словаря в  Json. Можно подробнее?

Comment: Это либо невалидный JSON (как уже сказано, нет запятой), либо некорректный JSONL (удалены нужные переводы строк и добавлены неправильные).